# How to debug slow wifi speed over TPLINK router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

**PROBLEM**: The wifi speeds from the router are never same as the speed that the wired connection provides. I pay for a 75Mbps speed. The wired connections deliver a consistent 70Mbps but the wifi connection from the router delivers far lower speed. [More details about wifi speed below]

**Relevant details**:
 - Router and modem are running **latest stock firmware**.
 - Speed tests were done using **google.com's speed test**. Here is a link to the picture of that speed test for your reference [speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kLJg.png)
 - I own a **TP-LINK WR841N(US)** router v14 (300 Mbps) that is connected to a Motorolla 8X4 DOCSIS 3.0 cable modem (**model: MB7220**).
 - I have tested and observed that wired connection from router/modem deliver the speed that I pay for ( around 75Mbps ). I have checked with the internet provider that both the modem and the router are **compatible**.
 - I have connected **two different machines running linux and windows** with 2 different wireless cards. Both of them receive a lower speed of around 25 Mbps.
 - **The speed is not stable**. It jumps between lows ( 0.5 Mbps) and highs ( 40 Mbps ) but is never stable.
 - The speed declines with distance very quickly. I have a really small room. Placing the router right outside the door drops the speed to 25 Mbps with the door closed.
 - The only electrical equipment that I think can interfere with the signal ( at least according to me but correct me if I'm wrong ) is an oven and a **washing unit** (washer + dryer). At first I thought it might be interfering with the signal but then, I changed the location of the router and brought it right outside my door. Even then, the speed did not improve.
 - With current setup, the dryer is not within direct LOS between my machine and the router.
 - The speed is 75 Mbps when standing right over the router.
 - Most of my tests were conducted on a **ubuntu 18.04 LTS**.

**Wireless card information for the linux machine:** 
`description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 3160
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 93
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-46-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:48 memory:e4200000-e4201fff`

**Link speed for the wireless interface on my machine:**
`SSID: ------------------
freq: 2412
RX: 79604461 bytes (288526 packets)
TX: 7724488 bytes (38902 packets)
signal: -55 dBm
tx bitrate: 150.0 MBit/s MCS 7 40MHz short GI
bss flags:  short-slot-time
dtim period:    1
beacon int: 100`

**What did I try ?**
 - Disable IPv6 on ubuntu
       **RESULT**: Improved the speed slightly ( < 5Mbps ). (Based on speed tests again)
 - Tried different locations for my router
     **RESULT**: The closer the router is, better the speed is. But it doesn't improve beyond 30 Mbps
 - Tried switching between channels 1,6,11 ( and others )
  **RESULT**: The speed improves but the improvement is not consistent.

**Questions**
1. How do I figure out if it’s interference that is causing low wifi speeds. How do I remedy it ?
2. If the router's firmware is faulty, should I flash Open-wrt ? Can that help with the wifi speeds ? ( Although I think that may not possible since the router is a 4/32 model ).
3. If nothing works, what router should I buy ?

My focus is solve this problem and at the same time, get to know about any tools that can help me in the future as well.

Comment: "I have connected two different machines running linux and windows with 2 different wireless cards" What model was each of your wireless cards? What link speeds do the wireless cards report after they've connected to the router? (i.e. 54/150/300 Mbps). Are you using a 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz network?

Comment: @MrEthernet I have that information in the post above. The link speed for the wireless interface is 150 Mbps.

Comment: Try running a speed test from your cell phone on your WiFi. What model phone do you have? I have a Samsung S8+ and get 330 Mbps download on my WiFi, which is much faster than a 2008 laptop I have. Modern cell phones can be useful for helping to narrow down the problem. If your phone is also slow, your router is likely the problem, but if you see a dramatic speed increase on your phone, then the wireless cards on your other wireless devices is likely the bottleneck.

Comment: "The link speed for the wireless interface is 150 Mbps". So on your Windows device, if you type `ncpa.cpl` in the Run dialogue box (Windows + R) then click Ok, then double click on the wireless adapter icon, it shows 150 Mbps under Speed? If so, is this link speed consistent or are you seeing it fluctuate at all?

Comment: @MrEthernet Yes. I observed a significantly higher speeds on my iphone 8+ and much more stable as well. My laptop delivered ~30 Mbps and that too was unstable. But my iphone delivered ~60Mbps. That's surprising too be honest. I thought laptops were designed to be more robust. If I'm not wrong, I can still remedy this with an external USB wireless adapter. Can you guide on that contingency as well ? OR if I need to invest in another router ?

Comment: "But my iphone delivered ~60Mbps" That's great! Whatever speed your fastest device gets is a speed that *all* of your devices would be able to get, if they had a good enough wireless adapter. " I have tested and observed that wired connection from router/modem deliver the speed that I pay for ( around 75Mbps)" Okay, so even though your wireless speeds are better on your iPhone (60 Mbps), your wired Ethernet speeds are still faster (75 Mbps). Personally, I would replace that wireless N router with a wireless AC router, which should allow your iPhone to see your full 75 Mbps over WiFi.

Comment: After replacing the outdated wireless N router with a model that supports wireless AC, I would run speed tests on the laptops and iPhone again and see what changes. Prediction: the iPhone should then easily get 75 Mbps download and most likely the laptops also. Also, once the new router is up and running, connect the laptops to the 2.4 GHz then 5 GHz wireless network and run a speed test on each one. Make a note of the download speed you get with each, then tell the operating system to forget the slower wireless network and leave them connected to the faster one!

Comment: Try running the router in 20mhz channel mode. 40mhz may be worse depending on co-channel interference from neighboring routers. 40mhz channels technically span more than one traditional 2.4ghz channel, increasing the chances of interference from neighbors. 1,6, & 11 are the non-overlapping channels for the 2.4ghz band. Try changing the channel and throughput test on each one